# How dispose Global key from provider with flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-provider

Want to build drawer with flutter web. But got
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
instance is moved to the new location. The key was:

- [LabeledGlobalKey#c9754]

GlobalKey reparenting is:

- MainScreen(dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _MainScreenState#dc897)
  A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class MenuController with ChangeNotifier {
          GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> get scaffoldKey => _scaffoldKey;
    
      void controlMenu() {
        if (!_scaffoldKey.currentState!.isDrawerOpen) {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
        }
      }
    
      // void disposeKey() {
      //   _scaffoldKey.currentState.();
      // }
    }

    class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        print('init CALLED- GAME---');
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        print('DISPOSE CALLED- GAME---');
        context.read<MenuController>().scaffoldKey.currentState!.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: context.read<MenuController>().scaffoldKey,
          drawer: SideMenu(),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // We want this side menu only for large screen
                if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
                  Expanded(
                    // default flex = 1
                    // and it takes 1/6 part of the screen
                    child: SideMenu(),
                  ),
                Expanded(
                  // It takes 5/6 part of the screen
                  flex: 5,
                  child: DashboardScreen(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }}
```

then want to reuse key from another widget

```
    class ProductsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: context.read<MenuController>().scaffoldKey,
          drawer: SideMenu(),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // We want this side menu only for large screen
                if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
                  Expanded(
                    // default flex = 1
                    // and it takes 1/6 part of the screen
                    child: SideMenu(),
                  ),
                Expanded(
                  // It takes 5/6 part of the screen
                  flex: 5,
                  child: ProductsListScreen(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

and got bug

To navigate inside SideMenu widget use

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ProductsScreen(),
                ),
              );
```

Comment: as I remember this can be fixed by reassigning a value to your global key on each build

Comment: thanks, how a can do it? tried context.read<MenuController>().scaffoldKey.currentState.dispose on dispose context.read<MenuController>().scaffoldKey.currentState.build(context) on init but doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to manually dispose of a `GlobalKey`. The main requirement is that they cannot be inserted into the widget tree twice. This is not the case with other keys (`LocalKey`s):

```dart
// this is allowed
Row(
  children: [
    SizedBox(key: Key('hello')),
    Container(key: Key('hello')),
  ],
)

// this is not
final key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
Row(
  children: [
    Scaffold(key: key),
    Scaffold(key: key),
  ],
)
```

A common reason why this is violated is animations. While the animation between one page and another page is playing, both pages are in the widget tree, and if they have the same `GlobalKey`, an error will be thrown.

Calling `globalKey.currentState!.dispose()` actually disposes the `State` of the associated widget. You should not call this yourself.

Instead, provide a new `GlobalKey` to the second subtree or remove the old one before navigating to the new page.